# Phonegap application hides splashscreen too quickly

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a multi-platform Phonegap app and using the Phonegap Build service to build it and load it onto devices. I have followed documentation and searched extensively online but am still having trouble with the splashscreen. The app starts and displays the splashscreen for about 1 second, then there is a white flash, and occasionally there is also a flash of unstyled html before the page has loaded properly. I am trying to make the splashscreen last about 4 seconds and then show the initial page correctly without these annoying flashes - they have such a negative effect on the user experience and make it really feel unlike a mobile app.
I cant get any of the suggested elements of the config.xml file to work to specify splashscreen delay.

I have tested this on iPad 2, iPhone 4s and the newest Google Nexus and all 3 devices have this problem, iPhone being the slowest and the Nexus showing a very fast flash but still a flash nonetheless.

I am using the latest version Phonegap Build, and jQuery mobile for the UI and page transitions so am wondering if that is anything to do with it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this in the config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

and when you want to hide, in the .js file

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

Comment: I have tried this and it hasnt worked. I have navigator.splashscreen.hide() inside an onDeviceReady function which is definitely being hit because other code works inside it. I've just realised though - if I use splashscreen.hide() straight away it causes the problem I described, however if I wrap it in a setTimeout of 5 seconds, the same thing happens visually but my app's 'index-page' is visible but completely unresponsive for the 5 seconds, WEIRD! It's like the time for the splashscreen is working but it's not actually displaying it on screen if that makes sense? Poor explanation I know

Comment: Its weird, it running well to me, You had seen the documentation (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/doc/index.md) I guess, and install the plugin, what version of phonegap are you using?

Comment: Yeah I've seen all that and I've followed it and checked it all over and over and it's not going well. I'm using the latest versions of the API: PhoneGap 3.4.0 and PhoneGap Build 3.3. Also, I'm using both the notifications.dialogs feature for popups etc and the network-information one and they're both working fine. On a side note... the iOS7 status bar plugin is also not working for me at all. I'll just have to keep fiddling but it's supposed to be so simple and unfortunately I have no idea why these things dont work for me

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to what others have placed here, yes put the following in your config.xml,

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

and call

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

when you are ready to hide your splashscreen.  But  be sure you have added the splashscreen plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

as the splash screen **will show** (on iOS at least, not 100% sure if splashscreen works without the plugin on other platforms) without it, but you can't control the duration, or the hiding of it without the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for android:

**SplashScreenDelay (number in milliseconds, defaults to 3000)**: The amount of time the splash screen image displays.

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
```

Set this `<preference>` inside `res--> xml -->config.xml` file.

Source Link [here.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html#Android%20Configuration)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by deferring the

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

until a few animation frames into the apps life (although this depends on what your startup/render situation is like)

if youre using `fastdom`, the below will probably do, although you may need a larger defer depending on your use case

```
fastdom.defer(2, function () {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the solution that worked for me is to load a HTML locally from the WWW folder of the Build and call all my other pages from there. i ask you to check the compatibility of j Query with phonegap . pure java script is always recommended as they load faster with no library included.

Comment: The HTML is loading locally since it's a packaged application. And many apps have used jQuery mobile with Phonegap before and have been successful, the speed of jQuery would be un-noticeably different, especially since I have the library also locally within in the application. The rest of the app is really fast, it's just a problem with the splashscreen and how it initially loads

Comment: Agreed. keep images in launch images and now check for the problem . first launch images should be loaded then the HTML will be loaded . that's how i do the launch images and sizes can be found in general tab of X code ios

Comment: The image that I created for the splashscreen in www/res/screen/blablabla.png and it is being shown but only for a short period of time. I just cant get the api to work so it will display for longer. (And I'm using Windows8 and Visual Studio to code my app, not Xcode)